# Remove ToggleButton backgroung on activate state

Tags: wpf, styles, togglebutton

This is my `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton Width="100" Height="30" Margin="344,262,530,345" BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent"
              BorderBrush="#38abcf" FontFamily="Resources/#Buxton Sketch" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="14">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="OFF"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="ON"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Currently on activate state it's look like that:

[image]

And the `Background` color not changed although i set new property.

- Update

  ```
      <ToggleButton.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
              <Setter Property="Content" Value="Loops OFF"/>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                          <Border Width="100" Height="30" BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#38abcf">
                              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                          </Border>
                          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                              </Trigger>
                          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Content" Value="Loops ON"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                  </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </ToggleButton.Style>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override default template

```
     <ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="OFF"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Border Name="Border" Width="100" Height="30"   BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent"
                      BorderBrush="#38abcf">
                                       <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                   </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                                    
                                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" TargetName="Border" />    
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="ON"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: BTW i add another trigger for IsMouseOver (see my update), why this not working ?

Comment: Template has been overriden so you need to use ControlTemplate.Triggers. I updated.

Comment: This still not changing the border color, please see my update.

Comment: You need to specify TargetName which refers to object name you wany to change. ControlTemplate.Triggers are, by default, associated with ControlTemplate that is why TargetName property was introduced - to allow pointing objects. Take a look at updated answear. I recommend getting familiar with concept of ControlTemplate.